# Structure streaming: First n rows

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-flink

Recently, I encounter with the problem 'first n rows' in structure streaming during engineering with real-time data. I need to obtain the 50 newest event-time records as output, but structure streaming give me a whole unbounded table or several updated results. I search a lot online, and several methods is following:

(1) Using TTL, but I think that it is based on ingestion time, which is not my desired event-time;

(2) Using Flink to catch the newest event-time records. It is something messy to use flink and structure streaming in the meantime. As following, I have tried to use flink 1.6, statics is a table? I don't know how to process on because nothing output.

```
val source: KafkaTableSource = Kafka010JsonTableSource.builder()
.forTopic("BINANCE_BTCUSDT_RESULT")
.withKafkaProperties(properties)
.withSchema(TableSchema.builder()
 .field("timestamp", Types.SQL_TIMESTAMP)
 .field("future_max", Types.DOUBLE)
 .field("future_min", Types.DOUBLE)
 .field("close",Types.DOUBLE)
 .field("quantities",Types.DOUBLE).build())
.fromEarliest()
.build()
tableEnv.registerTableSource("statics", source)
val statics = tableEnv.scan("statics")
statics.?
```

Any body could tell me more about the solving method with the first n rows problem? If the problem is solved, how to post the dataframe into url?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Streaming is typically used in cases where the input stream is continuously arriving, whereas a query for "the 50 newest records" is only meaningful at a single point in time. As soon as a newer event arrives, the previous output is out-of-date -- so what are you expecting as a result? It makes sense that the result has to be updated as newer events arrive.

Comment: Flink also supports SQL, by the way. https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/table/

Comment: Yeah, the result is continuously updated. I use the output mode 'complete', and my goal is that inputting the 50 newest records into my deep learning model to predict the value of next time. But SSS in complete mode gives all the result, and in update mode gives insufficiency result.

Comment: Anderson, I have tried to use Flink 1.6. I find 'fetch' in table api is suitable to solve this question. But when I get data from Kafka010JsonTableSource, the source is not a table.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use Flink 1.5, as 1.6 isn't stable yet (in fact, 1.5 was just released).

When using event time with Flink, Flink needs to be aware of your timestamps, and it needs watermarks, which indicate the flow of event time. To do this with a Kafka010JsonTableSource, you should configure a [rowtime attribute](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/dev/table/sourceSinks.html#configuring-a-rowtime-attribute).

Note that fetch() is only available when using Flink SQL in batch mode.

Comment: You are right! Flink 1.6 isn't stable. I have to write an additional python script to limit the output to the model, which can't be solved in Flink and structure streaming.